# How to fix pg_dump error- ERROR: permission denied for schema topology

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
Postgres: version 14

Environment: Ubuntu 21.04 on EC2

postgres=# \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres

some_user=> \dn
   List of schemas
   Name   |  Owner   
----------+----------
 public   | postgres
 topology | postgres
(2 rows)
```

I notice the topology schema only appears when logged in as some_user.

I wish to dump a table, using the below command.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U some_user -d my_db | gzip > /tmp/my_db.dump.gz
```

However, I get the below error:

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE topology.topology IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

When I try to grant the required privileges the offending schema, the schema does not exist.
It's like some sort of anti-quantam schema, which ceases to exist when observed.

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA topology TO some_user;
ERROR:  schema "topology" does not exist
```

I have read a thread on a similar problem, however, the same error occurs when I try the solution given. [Change privileges on schema created by rdsadmin user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078346/change-privileges-on-schema-created-by-rdsadmin-user)

Comment: More information needed. **Add as text not images**: 1) Postgres version. 2) Where are you running this instance? 3) What is the output of `\dn` in `psql`?

Answer (score -1):

You probably might want to exclude the the ownership information of the said schema by including `--no-owner` to your `pg_dump` command.

`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U some_user -d my_db --no-owner | gzip > /tmp/my_db.dump.gz`.

Comment: pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U some_user -d my_db --no-owner| gzip > mappa.dump.gz
Password: 

pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology

pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE topology.topology IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

Comment: Have you tried changing your search_path? SET search_path TO public,pg_catalog;
Then try running the command again